# Extract Value from XML having same tag name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have XML variable defined below and its value.

I want to fetch the text defined between tag `<TextNodeChild>` in single query.

Kindly help.

```
Declare @XMLVariable = 
'<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <root>  
     <TextNodeParent>
         <TextNodeChild>12345</TextNodeChild>
         <TextNodeChild>67890</TextNodeChild>
         <TextNodeChild>12389</TextNodeChild>
     </TextNodeParent>
 </root>'
```

I need output like this:

```
12345
67890
12389
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far

Answer (score 1):

You could use the XQuery (i.e. `XML` query) `.nodes()` method

```
SELECT 
    TextNodeParent = n.value('.[1]', 'NVARCHAR(max)') 
FROM
    @XMLVariable.nodes('root/TextNodeParent/*') as p(n)
```

**EDIT :** If you want to just the select the `TextNodeChild` node data then little change in `xml` path  as follow

```
 @XMLVariable.nodes('root/TextNodeParent/TextNodeChild') as p(n)
```

Result

```
TextNodeParent
12345
67890
12389
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.

Comment: That will list **all** elements below `<TextNodeParent>` - not jsut the `<TextNodeChild>` nodes. In the sample, there are no other nodes - so this works - but as a general solution, it could fail if there were other elements stored under the `<TextNodeParent>` node

Answer (score 0):

@YogeshSharma's solution works - here - because you have nothing but `<TextNodeChild>` elements under your `<TextNodeParent>` node.

However, if you had various node, and you wanted to extract **only** the `<TextNodeChild>` ones and get their values (and ignore all others), you'd have to use something like this instead:

```
SELECT 
    TextNodeParent = XC.value('.', 'INT')
FROM
    @XMLVariable.nodes('root/TextNodeParent/TextNodeChild') as XT(XC)
```